# How can i deploy from github build folder to hostinger server?

Tags: github, deployment, hosting

I have a project which have directory structure like below and i am hosting the application on Hostinger.

[image: Project Structure]

The problem is I don't want to deploy the complete code to the server. I want to deploy only the build folder which contains required code only.

> There is only option to give the GitHub project URL. How can I deploy
>   from a specific folder?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [hostinger/example-app](https://github.com/hostinger/example-app), you can only specify the GitHub repo and URL.

If possible you could consider then using *two* GitHub repos:

- one for your main project
- one with the necessary code

And you would reference the second inside the first with a [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
That way:

- cloning the first repo would still get the second one content.
- you can specify the URL of the second repo (the one with only the necessary code to deploy) in `hostinger`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apache's .htaccess feature to tweak hosting settings, which is fully supported in hostinger.

Create an .htaccess file in the root of your repo with the contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !path-to-your-webroot/
RewriteRule (.*) path-to-your-webroot/$1 [L]
```